# How to aggregate unrelated tables with temporary column

Tags: php, mysql, database, select

Here's a tough cookie. I have two unrelated tables - **vegetable** and **fruit**. I wonder if it's possible to do all the following steps in one MySQL query:

1) `SELECT` **id** and **name** from both tables.

2) Append temporary column value - **tmp_type** - to each row found in (1). Type of vegetable = 1, fruit = 2.

3) Aggregate results from both tables and `ORDER BY` **name**.

So, something like this:

[image]

Any ideas? I really would like to do it on the database level instead of manipulating two table results in PHP controller, but  I'm not sure what's the best way to achieve the goal.

Comment: Look at 'union' with your **exact** definitions you have used.. It will do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Union query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT id, name, 2 AS tmp_type
    FROM fruit 

    UNION ALL

    SELECT id, name, 1 AS tmp_type
    FROM vegetable
) AS foo
ORDER BY name
```

Note I'm using a subquery for the ordering. You could do the ordering directly inside the union, but the syntax is a little wonky-looking for what should be a simple example: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

Comment: Hi, very nice, thaks. Not sure what's the exact purpose of the `AS foo` part. I understand it's optonal and the `ORDER BY` can go direclty after the closing bracket, right?

Comment: EDIT: **"Every derived table must have its own alias"** So, guess it needs the `AS foo` after all :)

Answer (score 2):

As a note:  the subquery is not necessary.  This should also work:

```
SELECT id, name, 2 AS tmp_type
FROM fruit 
UNION ALL
SELECT id, name, 1 AS tmp_type
FROM vegetable
ORDER BY name;
```

Comment: This will also be more efficient (at least in MySQL versions 5.5 and earlier), since it avoids (the unnecessary step of) materializing a derived table.